# Word to describe a person who has a lot of experience in a specific field

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who has significant experience in a particular field (for example, an artist who has worked in the music industry for more than 10 years).

There are some possibilities I have already considered, such as *worldly-wise* or *mature,* but these aren't quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Expert, Professional, Adept, Specialist.

Comment: How is this not simply *expert*?

Comment: @DanBron - You can work in a field for a long time without becoming an expert. Or alternatively you can acquire expertise relatively quickly. Time spent doing something and level of expertise aren't perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 4):

Some possibilities include: professional, expert, seasoned, knowledgeable, proficient or simply experienced.

In your case I would go with 'seasoned' as it forms a neat collocation:

Several exhibitions are devoted to **seasoned artists**.

Mr. Barry is a **seasoned artist**, with hundreds of exhibitions under his belt.

Now, because of expanding opportunities, dancers start troupes long before they are **seasoned artists**.

Answer (score 4):

You could also consider "veteran"

> [a person who has had long experience in a particular field.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/veteran)

How long the experience needs to be before one is considered a veteran is quite subjective but I have certainly seen it applied to quite young people.

> [At 30, Alicia Keys is a music industry veteran with 35m albums sold](http://www.theguardian.com/music/2011/jul/14/alicia-keys)

Answer (score 2):

An [*authority*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/authority) in their field:

> An accepted source of expert information or advice. - TFD

(adj: *authoritative*)

Comment: That's good, but Erik wanted an adjective, not a noun :)

Answer (score 1):

Not as common for artists, but a person who has extensive knowledge and expertise in a field is known in New York as a "maven". (From Yiddish, which is pervasive in the average New Yorker's vocabulary.) In fact, when you hear someone described as a "big muckety-muck" (big shot) it is a mid-western U.S. interpretation of the Yiddish "macha" or "big macha" - which is what we say in NY. Yiddish not only has a lot of great descriptive terms, but it's very onomatopoeic(?), so it easily becomes part of the lexicon.

Comment: Sure, down-vote me now... but when you hear "maven" in a movie or TV show, you will doubtless be appreciative of your new knowledge.

Comment: I was going to suggest maven before I realized it meant expertise but not necessarily experience.  You can be a maven with an intense interest in a field without necessarily much actual experience in it.  But I do like the word!

Comment: Why should Yiddish be "very onomatopoeic"? It is a Germanic language and as much onomatopoeic as any other Indo-European language.

Answer (score -1):

Doyen/Doyenne:

> The most respected or prominent person in a particular field. — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/doyen)

Comment: Please cite your sources.  I encourage you to take the [tour] of the site and see the [help].