# Term to describe a person with a lot of experience in the tech industry and experience in a specific company's systems and processes

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word similar to this link below,

[Word to describe a person who has a lot of experience in a specific field](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216157/word-to-describe-a-person-who-has-a-lot-of-experience-in-a-specific-field)

> 'a person who has a lot of experience in a specific field',

but specifically for the IT world...
There was a clever word that I heard which meant that someone had been around for a long time, and had built up a lot of experience and knowledge about their specific system and setup... something like "**Technical Equity**" but I don't think that was it, and now I don't remember it.

It was used in the context of,

> "Now that we've lost Person X, we lost all of their ***[Tech-Equity?]***
> which means that we have to re-learn everything that this person knew
> and re-solve all the problems that they could have previously answered
> quickly and easily by heart."

I appreciate any hints or guesses you might be willing to share.

Comment: Are you looking for tech-savvy or expertise?

Comment: Do you want to describe the person or their technical knowledge? The blank in the example sentence is looking for a word for their knowledge. You can clarify the title in that vein. _Know-how_ comes to mind but it can still be too general.

Comment: *Experience* would have this meaning - "when they retire, we're losing their 30 years' experience" - but I think there's another more jargony term.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these hyphenated words

"Tech-adept"

[Adept](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adept) (Wiktionary) Well skilled; completely versed; thoroughly proficient